# ExtJs Grid lines posting unwanted field / column values

Tags: extjs, model, grid, store

Need your help on below issue I am facing while posting grid lines to server

In my ExtJs (6.0.1) application, I have Grid with Store (Ext.data.Store) and Model defined. I have fields definitions in Model. The number of fields defined in Model for grid lines are less than the fields / columns returned from the server. I have included only those field definitions which are mandatory and are required to be displayed in Grid.

Data gets loaded in Grid successfully without any issues. However, while posting the data, i.e. Saving the grid lines after editing, I noticed, columns / fields are being submitted which are not part of the field definition in Model. I don't want that, I want to submit only those column / fields which are defined in Model. I think, when data is loaded in Grid, the Model definition is modified to include extra columns returned from server.

Can anyone please, suggest why this is happening ?

Another issue is that, if I edit any one of the column value in grid using POPUP window, it updates the values of other fields which are either empty string or 0. For those fields, values are being set to null, which is causing exception on server side as its expecting either Empty String or 0, and instead getting NULL.

I have tried many alternatives, however, no success. Please HELP !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly have a look at this guide about how to ask question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You need to post some code which you have tried so far. It is better to create a sencha fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Sencha decided so, citing performance reasons. In ExtJS 4.x, the model was required and had to be kept up to date. Nowadays, it is only seen as a loose guideline. If you want extra fields not to be submitted to the server (well, the server could safely ignore these posted values...), you have to add them to the model explicitly and add `persist:false`.

If I load data into a grid, and edit the record in a popup window with a form using `loadRecord` and `updateRecord`, the values that have no corresponding form fields are not overwritten. If one uses `getData` and `setData`, on the other hand, the values are overwritten. This is by design, because `getData`/`setData` is intended for raw processing, while `loadRecord`/`updateRecord` is intended for record editing.

Comment: I will give it a try and will let you know, Thanks for quick reply !